# Why is Python signal handler not getting triggered?

Tags: python, python-2.7, signals

In the code snippet below, I registered the signal handler with a call to `signal.signal`. However, though the process is killed after the timeout, the `print` or `system` statements inside the handler are not being executed. What am I doing wrong? I am running Python 2.7.15rc1 on Ubuntu 18.04, 64 bit.

```
import signal
import time
import os
import multiprocessing as mp

def handler(signal, frame):
    print "Alarmed"
    os.system('echo Alarmed >> /tmp/log_alarm')

def launch():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
    signal.alarm(5)
    print "Process launched"
    os.execv('/bin/cat', ['cat'])
    print "You should not see this"

p = mp.Process(target=launch)
p.start()
print "Process started"
p.join()
```

Comment: There are a number of system calls that you should not call from a signal handler. the `system` libc function makes several, such as forking a new process. You could just write a little Python to perform the same thing directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are at that point out of Python territory. `os.execv()` ultimately caused [`execve(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) syscall to be made and as its man page states:

> All process attributes are preserved during an execve(), except the
>    following:
>
> - The dispositions of any signals that are being caught are reset to
>     the default ([`signal(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)).
>
> ...

Which does make sense, you shouldn't really want to run some new code while having old handlers registered for it (and no idea how that could even work since handlers would also be replaced).

---

If you implemented `cat`-like behavior in python and did not `execve` a new process, it would have (more or less) worked the way you expected:

```
import signal
import time
import os
import sys
import multiprocessing as mp

def handler(signal, frame):
    print "Alarmed"
    os.system('echo Alarmed >> /tmp/log_alarm')
    sys.exit(0)

def launch():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
    signal.alarm(5)
    print "Process launched"
    stdin = os.fdopen(0)
    stdout = os.fdopen(1, 'w')
    line = stdin.readline()
    while line:
        stdout.write(line)
        line = stdin.readline()
    print "You may end here if EOF was reached before being alarmed."

p = mp.Process(target=launch)
p.start()
print "Process started"
p.join()
```

Note: I've just hard coded handling of stdin/stdout in the child process. And since you've mentioned python 2.7 I've avoided using `for line in stdin:`.